# Hashbytes Column

Tags: ssis, ssis-2012

I have a column with Hashbytes values: 0xDA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709 which is a Binary data type. I need to create a column as DA39A3EE5E6B4B0D3255BFEF95601890AFD80709 without 0x using ssis. I have tried various methods but I just end up strange characters such as 㧚歞ോ唲悕逘�इ.Thanks.

Comment: Are you generating the hashbytes from a sql query or the .NET library?

Comment: Im generating it from an SQL Query.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL, when you convert binary to string, you can set a flag in the convert statement that will preserve the text, like 20:

```
declare @b as varbinary(50) = hashbytes('sha1','somehash')

select @b
, Convert(varchar(50), @b)
, Convert(varchar(50), @b, 1)
, substring(Convert(varchar(50), @b, 1), 3, len(Convert(varchar(50), @b, 1))) --output without the 0x
```